# git http authentication problems on windows

Tags: windows, git, bash, http

I have a strange behaviour with git on Windows.

Some information

- Windows 7
- git version 1.9.5-preview20150319

If I try to clone a repository from the git bash with the http protocol like:

**git clone http://myhost/myRepository**

I get the error

**fatal: Authentication failed for http://myhost/myRepository**

If I clone the repository with the egit Eclipse plugin I'm able to clone it. 
Also If I try the same command on ubuntu (from the same machine, in a virtual machine), I'm able to clone the repository.

Any help to be able to use the bash console in windows? need it for some initial setup.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [credential] section in your gitconfig

```
[credential]
    helper = !\"C:/{msysgit-installation-path}/libexec/git-core/git-credential-wincred.exe\"
[http]
    sslverify = false
```

You can use `git config --global -e` to edit your git config

Comment: thank you @palazzo train

I've added that line but it doesn't help. 
Online I've found the use of wincred as a keystore, I've tried but that doesn't solve the problem too

Comment: Try to add one more section [http], see if it works?  I have edited my answer above

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem, prefacing my username with my htdigest realm ('REALM\USERNAME') fixed it for me. For some reason, it appears that the Linux client and others figure this out for you but the Windows client requires you to specify it explicitly.